# Lotus-1-2-3 dialog codes

Tags: lotus

I work in a building company supporting, and editing some legacy software. One of my 'favourites' is a spreadsheet we have in Lotus123 that is essentially used as an application through a series of dialogues and macros.
Now, for creating a dialogue, you are meant to use the dialogue editor. My predecessor, however, decided that he should create these all by hand. I have to edit and create more of these. At the moment I'm basically copying an old one and altering it through a combination of deduction and trial/error.
I wondered if any knew what all the various codes are, or if there's a list somewhere of them. A simple dialogue and code
I believe the columns for the main body go: starting x co-ord starting y co-ord width (x) depth (y) item ID (note, this must be unique to get the user return value) type ID (for example radio button as opposed to check box) type (e.g. button) name no idea, this field is always '0' in my spreadsheet default/startup value *value once the dialogue is closed
If any one can provide more detail, for example what the different types and type IDs are, or how to read the top line of the code (where the dialogue box is created), or even a link to a tutorial showing the dialogue code I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

On the SmartSuite CD should should find the SmartSuite developer documentation, or you can get it here ftp://ftp.lotus.com/pub/lotusweb/product/smartsuite/devapp.pdf

I checked and it doesn't document this, Why can't you load the dialog in the dialog editor?